# java.lang.AssertionError: No value at JSON path "$[0].sClientAcctId"

Tags: spring-data-jpa, mockito, junit4, querydsl

I am trying to write test case for Account controller class. Account controller is depends on Account service class so I am using `mockito`. In Account Service I am using `Querydsl` for creating dynamic query for implementing search filter.

I tried to write test case like below. In that test class I am able to receive query result in array format. But I am getting empty body and because of that getting this error  `java.lang.AssertionError: No value at JSON path "$[0].sClientAcctId"`

Can any one tell me why I am getting empty body?

**AccountController**

```
        @GetMapping("/findAccountData")
        public ResponseEntity<List<Tuple>> populateGridViews(@RequestParam(value="sClientAcctId",required=false) String sClientAcctId,
                                                             @RequestParam(value="sAcctDesc",required=false) String sAcctDesc,
                                                             @RequestParam(value="sInvestigatorName",required=false)String sInvestigatorName,
                                                             @RequestParam(value="sClientDeptId",required=false) String sClientDeptId) throws Exception {
            return  ResponseEntity.ok(accService.populateGridViews(sClientAcctId, sAcctDesc,sInvestigatorName,sClientDeptId));
        }
```

**TestAccountControllerGrid**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class TestAccountControllerGrid {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;   

    @Mock
    private AccountService accountService;

    @InjectMocks
    private AccountController accountController;

    @Autowired
    EntityManager em;

    @Value("${InstituteIdentifier}")
    private String instituteIdentifier;

    @Test
    @Transactional
    public void populateGridViewsTest() throws Exception {

        String sClientAcctId ="1110720";
        String sAcctDesc ="DR DE DUVE";
        String sInvestigatorName ="Acquaviva, Adelaide";
        String sClientDeptId ="110720";


        Department departmentObject = new Department();     
        departmentObject.setsClientDeptId("110720");
        departmentObject.setsDeptName("de Duve Laboratory");
        departmentObject.setnInstId(60);
        departmentObject.setbIsLocked(false);
        departmentObject.setbAlternateJointusePercentage(true);

        Investigator investigatorObject= new Investigator();    
        investigatorObject.setsInvestigatorName("Acquaviva, Adelaide");
        investigatorObject.setnInstId(60);

        Account accountObject = new Account();      
        accountObject.setsAcctDesc(" ASTRALIS LTD");
        accountObject.setsClientAcctId("5400343");
        accountObject.setsLocation("A");
        accountObject.setnAccountCPCMappingId(123);
        accountObject.setnAgencyId(20356);

        Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
        accountObject.setdEndDate(timestamp );
        accountObject.setDepartment(departmentObject);
        accountObject.setInvestigator(investigatorObject);

        em.merge(accountObject);

        QAccount account = QAccount.account;

        JPAQuery<Tuple> query = new JPAQuery<Tuple>(em);
        List<Tuple> result = query.select(account.sAcctDesc, account.sClientAcctId,account.sLocation)
                                  .from(account).fetch();   

        System.out.println("Query Result = "+ result);       

        Mockito.when(accountService.populateGridViews(sClientAcctId, sAcctDesc, sInvestigatorName, sClientDeptId))
        .thenReturn(result);        


        mockMvc.perform(get("/spacestudy/"+instituteIdentifier+"/admin/account/findAccountData")
                .param("sClientAcctId", "1110720")
                .param("sAcctDesc", "DR DE DUVE")
                .param("sInvestigatorName", "Acquaviva, Adelaide")
                .param("sClientDeptId", "110720")
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                )
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].sAcctDesc", is("DR DE DUVE")))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].sClientAcctId", is("1110720")))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].sLocation", is("ON")))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].department.sDeptName", is("de Duve Laboratory")))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].investigator.sInvestigatorName", is("Acquaviva, Adelaide")));

        //Mockito.verify(accountService).populateGridViews(sClientAcctId, sAcctDesc, sInvestigatorName, sClientDeptId);
    }
```

Comment: First of all your service expected 4 parameters, but in `mockMvc.perform.param` you are declare only 3. Did your `List<Tuple> result` is empty ??, if yes your mocked call also will return empty and you got empty body. Try to do `Mockito.when(accountService.populateGridViews(Mockito.any(),Mockito.any(), Mockito.any(), Mockito.any())).thenReturn(result)` if it works correct step by step change the parameters, maybe some typo errors. At the end you do need `Mockito.verify` because of if your mock works incorrect you are will not get expected result.

Comment: List<Tuple> result is not empty. you can see that result on console i.e. `Query Result`

Comment: Did you try with `Mockito.any()`??

Comment: with `Mockito.any()` also not working getting same error. still body is empty

Comment: i think problem in your controller bean, in controller class `accService` is not the mock, please provide your controller class code. If you use `@Mock` you should declare implementation class instead of interface.

Comment: I added controller class and service class code

Comment: Please check in controller class during testing, the injected service is mock or not ?

Comment: I got result in body and test cases also running. but its calling actual account service method and actual db. when I am checking `mockito.verify` I am getting zero interaction with mock

Comment: Try to use `@MockBean` instead of `@Mock`. For `@Mock` and `@InjectMock` you need another Runner, and injecting controller in test is not necessary, because of `@AutoConfigureMockMvc`.